# mention user counting in text

Tags: javascript, regex

Here I have a string with @mention user but I don't want to count any users with a space, dot, comma, hyphen.

```js
var str= `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 
@portpofili.9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393`;
var pattern = /@\b[-?(\w+)?]+\b/gi;
var count = (str.match(pattern) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Here the result is 10 but I need 8. How could I do that? Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Uu9Eav/2/ I see 10 matches

Comment: @PhilippSander "but I need 8", they don't want to include the one's like `@portpofili.9393` or `@portpofili-9393`

Comment: I can't read... I'm sorry

Comment: Have are valid usernames composed? is it just characters and digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `[-?(\w+)?]` consists of a character class which matches any of the listed characters (which could also be written as `[-+?()\w]`

What you might do is match 1+ word characters and assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char `\S` using a negative lookahead `(?!`:

```
@\w+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1MqEV6/1)

```js
var str= `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 
@portpofili.9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393`;
var pattern = /@\w+(?!\S)/gi;
var count = (str.match(pattern) || []).length;
console.log(count)
```

If what comes before can only be the start of the string or a space you could match that using an alternation and capture the @mention in a group:

```
(?:^|\s)(@\w+)(?!\S)
```

```js
var str = `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
@portpofili.9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393 @portpofili.9393@portpofili9394 @@test`;
var pattern = /(?:^|\s)(@\w+)(?!\S)/gi;
var count = (str.match(pattern) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

An example to get the values from the group:

```js
var pattern = /(?:^|\s)(@\w+)(?!\S)/gi;
const str = `@test
@portpofili.9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393

@portpofili.9393-j @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393-8 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393

@portpofili.9393@portpofili9394
@@test

@testing`;
let m;
while ((m = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === pattern.lastIndex) {
    pattern.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Everything is good, When I type @portpofili.9393@portpofili9394 It is counting 1 but this is an invalid word. could you help me that how can I ignore this?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much

Comment: @Shohel Or use a capturing group `(?:^|\s)(@\w+(?!\S))`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1MqEV6/4)

Answer (score 5):

Your regex needs to be modified:

@[^.\s-]+(?=\s|$)

@ followed by anything not being .,- or whitespace until the next character is a whitespace or the end of the input.

```js
var str= `Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 
@portpofili.9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393
@portpofili-9393 @portpofili9394 @portpofili9395 @portpofili9393 @portpofili9393`;
var pattern = /@[^.\s-]+(?=\s|$)/gi;
var count = (str.match(pattern) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Everything is good, When I type @portpofili.9393@portpofili9394 It is counting 1 but this is an invalid word. could you help me that how can I ignore this?

Comment: just do `@[^.\s-]+(?=\s|$|@)` to make it to two valid users or `@[^.\s-@]+(?=\s|$)` to make it invalid

Comment: Did not work for this value @portpofili.9393@portpofili9394

Comment: Invalid yould be `(?<!\S)@[^.\s-@]+(?=\s|$)`

Comment: And valid would be `@[^.\s-@]+(?=\s|$|@)`